# IBM Web Administration for i .. Web Services Wizards

Tags: xml, web-services

Looking for help with the *Web Services Wizard*.  I have created/deployed a REST service that should accept a "POST" xml statement.  I am currently receiving the following errors:  
**Test Side:** 
*HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type*
  **On the Web Service Side:** 
*The system cannot find any method in the iseries.wsbeans.'Web Service Name.Resource' class that comsumes text/xml media type.  Verify that a method exists that consumes the media type Specified.* 
The Server Configuration file includes **DefaultType text/xml**.  
  I cannot determine where, while using the wizard, how to define/determine the media type.  
  Thank you 
 Don S.

Answer (score 0):

Probably when you deployed this service you not set accept input media as *ALL. 
If you set in this value *JSON or *XML or both you should set Content-Type as application/json or application/xml not as text/xml.

This value is setting in 5 step on creator ("Implementation of a new service" -> step 5 ->  field: "Allowed types of input media")